# Strange Behavior in xcode 5 (While opening my old ios app)

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have a created a universal application in iOS . It worked well on both iPhone and iPad. Few days ago i updated my Xcode version to 5, now i see some strange behavior with my project. When i open my project xib files all labels,buttons and images are not present in the screen. So when see my labels , buttons frame size it all set to (0,490,0,0). label and button width and height should be zero. I have 20 more xib screens so i don't want to align manually all those screens.

is it possible to fix?

Thanks in advance…….

Notes:

```
- My iPad xib do not changed. Only iPhone xib has changed.
- I don't have repository account for this project.
- I have another mac with xcode4.5 , and when i open my project it works good. Do i need    to change any autoresizing mask in xcode4.5 to fix this issue?
- I don't use auto layout , story board in my project.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when you change in `Storyboard` or `xib` **File inspector** > **Interface builder document** > **View as** from 'iOS 6.1 and earlier' to 'iOS 7 or later' and inversely.

To make your interface look right you have to repair it manually.

Comment: I changed my xib settings like below

Comment: I changed my xib settings like below

File inspector > Interface builder document
Opens in Xcode 4.6
View as 'iOS 6.1 and earlier'
But this is not fixed my issue. As you said we have to repair it manually. Ok how can i view my old design with this Xcode? to align properly

Comment: It applies to XCode 5. If you don't have snapshot or repository, there is nothing you can do to revert it. To circumvent this problem in the future use Interface Builder constraints.

Comment: Ok . i got it. One more question, as i said earlier i have another mac with Xcode 4.5. i can update my project in repository with old Xcode and get it in new xcode5(in another mac).  If possible tell me how can i do this?